# npm run production error I can't decipher

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I can't understand the error when executing `npm run production`:

```
$ npm run production

> @ production /var/www/html
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 91% additional asset processingnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                              
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-10-26T07_24_01_397Z-debug.log
```

Here is the `/home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-10-26T07_24_01_397Z-debug.log` file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'production' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preproduction', 'production', 'postproduction' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preproduction: @
6 info lifecycle @~production: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~production: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~production: CWD: /var/www/html
10 silly lifecycle @~production: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~production: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~production: Failed to exec production script
13 verbose stack Error: @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-1069-aws
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "production"
18 verbose node v10.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ production script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{

    "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.1.10"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"
      }
    }
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me before.

The fix that worked for me was to update the paths in package.json. cross-env must have updated its paths, it has "cross-env/dist/bin" not "cross-env/bin/"

make a backup, switch to these ones and try again.

```
"dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

I hope that helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

After, run this command

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install
```

Comment: Now running `npm run production` gives me the error `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/html/public/css/app.css'`

Comment: @cawecoy are you using Ubuntu? Give permission to access the file, I'm a windows user, I do not know about the command of ubuntu